# Cucumber-JVM: Execute the steps from another Scenario/ScenarioOutline given the scenario's visual text

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have two scenarios, and I want to execute the steps of one scenario inside the other scenario, dynamically:

```
@scenario-a
Scenario: My scenario A
Given I do Step1
When I do Step2
Then I do Last Step

@scenario-b
Scenario: My Scenario B
Given I do Step1
When I reuse "My Scenario A"
Then I do Last Step
```

Basically, I want pass the scenario as an argument in the 'I reuse "My Scenario A"' step of Scenario B, and executes the steps of Scenario A. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber doesn't support this and you really don't want to do this. What will happen if you do is at some point you will modify scenario-a, and at that point you will break some/all of the scenarios that depend upon it.

Instead what you need do is find a name for the behaviour in scenario-a. Lets say scenario-a is signing in. Then scenario-a is all about proving you can sign in i.e. developing the sign in behaviour. Scenario-b wants to use this behaviour to develop some different behaviour e.g. setting my email preferences. Here is how we do this.

```
Scenario: I can sign in
  Given I am registered
  When I sign in
  Then I should be signed in
```

the interesting part of this is `When I sign in`, lets look at how to implement that  (all code is pseudo ruby)

```
When "I sign in" do
  sign_in user: @i
end
```

and

```
module SignInStepHelper
  def sign_in(user: )
    visit login_path
    fill_in username with user.email
    fill_in password with user.password
    submit_form
  end
end
World SingInStepHelper
```

Now we have that behaviour we can use that in scnenario-b

```
Scenario: Set email preferences
  Given I am registered
  And I am signed in
  When I set my email preferences
  Then ...
```

To re-use our behaviour we write another step. This is really important: the best way to get re-use with cucumber is have steps re-use methods NOT to re-use steps.

```
Given "I am signed in" do
  sign_in user: @i
end
```

See how we have re-used our sign_in behaviour without having to do anything clever with Cucumber (we are just making the same call in a different step definition). Notice also the change in tense and how well that works `When I sign in` vs `Given I am signed in`.

This approach pushes HOW you do things down from Cucumber into your programming language and can be used for any behaviour you develop

Answer (score 0):

To handle such case, we create a single line step which in turn will have serious of test steps inside glue function. My suggest would be similar to what @diabolist already said. Given that you're testing online shopping application and you just want to reuse the scenario of adding a product to cart as

```
# Below scenario is very basic one to ensure if user can place an order
Scenario: To check if a product can be added to cart
Given when i login to onlineshopping.com as bhuvanesh
When i search for product "google home mini"
And set quantity of product to "3"
Then add product to cart
And setting shipping address as "1, Street name, city, state - 12345"
When i place the order
Then order confirmation should be displayed to user

#Now that i want to do extensive testing by adding more products to cart
Scenario: To check if shopping cart can hold upto 100 products(max size)
Given when i login to onlineshopping.com as bhuvanesh
When add item "Product=google home mini#Count=2" to shipping cart
And add item "Product=google home#Count=3" to shipping cart
add item "Product=Google Pixel2#Count=10" to shipping cart
add item "Product=Apple Ipad Mini4#Count=20" to shipping cart
### and so in
And setting shipping address as "1, Street name, city, state - 12345"
When i place the order
Then order confirmation should be displayed to user
```

So if you look at above 2 scenarios, i have combined the steps 2,3 and 4 from scenario 1 which are steps repeated in Scenario2's step2,3,4...

We term such step which comprising of multiple steps in it as "Super-step" (you can call it as scenario) and use it wherever you want to. This one of the way to handle your case.